# How to filter table view cells with a UISegmentedControl in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2, uisegmentedcontrol

I've already searched this before asking the question but I didn't find what I need.

I'm building this app where the user puts a task (not going to the app store, just for me and some friends), and the task has a category. For example: school, home, friends, etc. When the user is going to add a new task, there are 2 text fields, the description text field and the category text field. I'm using a UIPickerView so the user picks a category, then, after creating the new task, it will add the category to an array I've created called "categories".

I want to put an UISegmentedControl on top of the table view with the sections:

All - School - Home - Friends

If all is selected, it will show all the cells with no filtering. If not, it will show the cell(s) with the corresponding categories.

I've read that I need to create table view sections to each category, but this would change my code a lot, and I don't even have an idea of how to work with multiple table view sections, I've tried once but it kept repeating the cells of one section in the second.

So how can I filter the cells per category?

Can I just put for example this? :

```
if //code to check in which section the picker is here {
   if let schoolCell = cell.categories[indexPath.row] == "School" {
        schoolCell.hidden = true
   }
}
```

Please help me!!!

EDIT:

I have this code by now:

```
if filterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            if categories[indexPath.row] == "School" {

            }
    }
```

I just don't know where to go from here. How do I recognize and hide the cells?

Comment: You should filter your data (array, etc) and just reload table view

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you may want to take a simpler approach first and get something working. Set up your ViewController and add a tableView and two(2) arrays for your table data. One would be for home and the other for work. Yes, I know this is simple but if you get it working, then you can build on it.

Add a variable to track which data you are displaying.

```
@IBOutlet var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

// You would set this to 0, 1 or 2 for home, work and all.
var dataFilter = 0

// Data for work tasks    
var tableDataWork : [String] = ["Proposal", "Send mail", "Fix printer", "Send payroll", "Pay rent"]
// Data for home tasks
var tableDataHome : [String] = ["Car payment", "Mow lawn", "Carpet clean"]
```

Add these functions for the segmented control.

```
@IBAction func segmentedControlAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {

        case 0:
            print("Home")
            dataFilter = 0
        case 1:
            print("Work")
            dataFilter = 1
        case 2:
            print("All")
            dataFilter = 2
        default:
            print("All")
            dataFilter = 2
    }
    reload()

}

func reload() {
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("task-cell")

    var title: String?
    switch dataFilter {
        case 0:
            title = tableDataHome[indexPath.row]
        case 1:
            title = tableDataWork[indexPath.row]
        case 2:
            if indexPath.row < tableDataWork.count {
                title = tableDataWork[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                title = tableDataHome[indexPath.row - tableDataWork.count]
        }
        default:
            if indexPath.row < tableDataWork.count {
                title = tableDataWork[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                title = tableDataHome[indexPath.row + tableDataWork.count]
            }
    }
    cell?.textLabel?.text = title


    if cell != nil {
        return cell!
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // If
    switch dataFilter {
    case 0: return tableDataHome.count
    case 1: return tableDataWork.count
    default: return tableDataHome.count + tableDataWork.count
    }
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1;
}
```

You can find the entire project here: https://github.com/ryantxr/segmented-control-app

Comment: I realized that even if it works, the cells would be out of order, I would just going to change the category label, but not the task label for example, so it could possible show other cell's task instead of its own. I'll have a look, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your tableview.

If you use NSFetchedResultsController then you need to modify your fetch request. If you use an array directly, just use the filter function in Swift, passing in the condition, e.g. `filteredArray = array.filter{$0.isAudioFile}` Then, after setting your datasource array to the filtered one, call `reloadData` on your tableview.

You will need to keep a reference to the full array, and use the filtered one as your datasource in `cellForRow...`

Comment: How can I use this .filter function to filter for the category string? I've tried "categories.filter("School")" but it's giving me an error. How to use it, and what are "throws"?

Comment: So, the filter function takes the query, you need to pass $0 for the object being queried, and the property and condition. E.g. someArray.filter{$0.category = "School"}. $0 represents every object in the array that will be checked for its category matching School

Comment: Not working :(
I think I'll need to give up the idea. Maybe the only way is to create sections...